# How to create a SQL Tables that updates when the date changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently I'm creating an app that can essentially create post-it notes. I'm working on making my SQL tables for it. What I want to do is make it so the tables data is searchable by date. Multiple posts may be made on a day obviously. So I'm putting the date into a separate table. What I'm wondering is if it's possible to make it so the date column on the date table is not the current date that it will auto increment the Id and create a new column with the current date

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ideas (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
ideas text, 
date_id int    );


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS date (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
table_date CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), GETDATE(),10));
```

Is the code I have so far any and all suggestions are welcome!

Comment: it's SQL code no ? I removed the SQL-server code tag maybe i'm mistaken. Do you mean it's not correct syntax or that this is a different type of SQL. This is typical of what I would write to communicate with PGAdmin and Postgres for communicating with my databases.

Comment: The tag `sql-server` tag refers to the database product "Microsoft SQL Server" which is something very different to Postgres.

Comment: I don't think having the dates in a separate table is a good idea. Just add a column `created_at` with type `timestamp` (or `date` if you don't need the time) to your `ideas` table. And: **never**, _ever_ store dates as `varchar`. **Never**. Just don't

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `TRIGGER` procedure. You can trigger a function every time an insert is made on the `ideas` table. This function can check the `dates` table and make sure the current date exists in there. It can even set the new id of that date in the `date_id` column in the `ideas` table.

For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ideas;
CREATE TABLE ideas (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ideas text, 
  date_id int
);

-- "date" is a reserved word. try to avoid naming a table "date".
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dates;
CREATE TABLE  dates (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  table_date DATE DEFAULT NOW() -- i would recommend the DATE type here
);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insert_date_if_absent ON ideas;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS insert_date_if_absent();

CREATE FUNCTION insert_date_if_absent()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
DECLARE
  today date := now();
  new_date_id integer;
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dates WHERE table_date = today) THEN
    INSERT INTO dates (table_date) VALUES (today) RETURNING id INTO new_date_id;
  ELSE
    SELECT id FROM dates WHERE table_date = today INTO new_date_id;
  END IF;
  IF NEW.date_id IS NULL THEN
    NEW.date_id := new_date_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_date_if_absent
    BEFORE INSERT ON ideas
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_date_if_absent();
```

This will allow you to omit `date_id` when inserting into `ideas`. If omitted, it will get automatically set by the trigger to the id of today's date.

```
INSERT INTO ideas (ideas) VALUES ('sup dudeee');
```

Some other feedback which I incorporated in my answer:

- Do not store dates as a `VARCHAR`, it's less efficient and more hassle. Use a `DATE` instead.
- Do not name tables after reserved words in Postgres. Rather than `date`, name it `dates`.